# phonegap iOS file upload using input(file)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am just developing a file upload app to local server using phone gap for iOS. I am using **input type file** in html for getting the **file path** and used **File plugin** for uploading.

This is my file upload code.

```
var fileup = new FileTransfer();
fileup.upload(filepath, uri, win, fail, options);
```

But i am getting the file path as "c:\fakepath\somefile" and not the original file path. Is it possible to get the actual file path using input type file in html or any way to overcome this issue. Kindly guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use file transfer if you are using input file, use XHR to send the whole form data instead:

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormIdHere"));
jQuery.ajax({
    url: uri,
    data: data,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert('error');
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success');                 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other way to upload file without using input type file in ios using phonegap?..

Comment: You can use camera plugin to take the picture or pick it from the gallery and the use file transfer to upload it.

Comment: i need to upload all type of files is it possible to use camera plugin.

Comment: With camera plugin you can only upload images. With input file you can upload images and videos. For other file types, you can upload them using file transfer, but the difficult part is to pick them as you can only access files inside the app.